# OnClose not called in ServerEndpoint with Java EE websocket

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I have a simple websocket endpoint, using the `javax.websocket` library, but the method intercepting with the *OnClose* annotation is never called even though *OnOpen* and *OnMessage* are called. I've tried subclassing `ServerEndpoint` as well without any luck.

This is my code

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/cont")
public class ContinousWebsocketExample {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContinousWebsocketExample.class);

    private int counter = 0;
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session client, EndpointConfig config) {
        LOGGER.debug("---------------------------Opening websocket connection-----------------------------------");
        while (true) {
            client.getAsyncRemote().sendText("Counter is: " + counter);
            counter ++;
            LOGGER.debug(String.valueOf(client.isOpen()));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session client, CloseReason reason) {
        LOGGER.debug("---------------------------Closing websocket connection-----------------------------------");
    }
}
```

And the relevant Javascript:

`var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/cont')
 socket.close();`

The program keeps on printing the counter even after the frontend closed the socket. However, `client.isOpen()` returns *false* after the frontend has closed the connection.

Comment: what happens if you do not have a never ending loop in `onOpen`

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Nice catch!

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do you know of any way to force close a websocket when it is doing work, except for having the interruption as a message? Because I'm assuming this same behavior will happen when the websocket server is doing some actual useful work as well.